# Unable to read data from camera, is it a possible bug in JavaCV 1.1

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I was trying to learn how to use javacv for capturing video via pc camera. I got this webcamtest file

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;


public class WebcamTest extends JFrame{

    protected double scale = 1.0;   
    protected boolean mirror = true;                
    protected int width, height;                
    protected BufferedImage image;                  
    private Grabby grabby;                          
    private JComponent canvas;                      
    private FrameGrabber grabber;           

    public WebcamTest() {
        super("Webcam");

        // Create our graphics-handling component.
        canvas = new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

        // Set up webcam
        grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0); 
        // Repeated attempts following discussion on javacv forum, fall 2013 (might be fixed internally in future versions)
        final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
        int attempt = 0;
        System.out.print("Initializing camera");
        while (attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            System.out.print('.');
            attempt++;
            try {
                grabber.start();
                break;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        if (attempt == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            System.err.println("Failed after "+attempt+" attempts");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("done");

        // Get size and figure out scaling
        width = grabber.getImageWidth();
        height = grabber.getImageHeight();
        System.out.println("Native camera size "+width+"*"+height);
        if (scale != 1) {
            width = (int)(width*scale);
            height = (int)(height*scale);
            System.out.println("Scaled to "+width+"*"+height);
        }

        // Set the size as determined by the grabber.
        setSize(width, height);     

        // Boilerplate to finish initializing the GUI.
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        getContentPane().add(canvas);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        // Spawn a separate thread to handle grabbing.
        grabby = new Grabby();
        grabby.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Handles grabbing an image from the webcam (following JavaCV examples)
     * storing it in image, and telling the canvas to repaint itself.
     */
    private class Grabby extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
            Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                IplImage grabbed = null;
                while (grabbed == null) {
                    try {
                        grabbed = grabberConverter.convert(grabber.grab());
                    }   
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("failed grab");
                        Thread.sleep(100); // wait a bit
                    }
                }
                if (mirror) {
                    cvFlip(grabbed, grabbed, 1);
                }
                if (scale != 1) {
                    IplImage resized = IplImage.create(width, height, grabbed.depth(), grabbed.nChannels());
                    cvResize(grabbed, resized);
                    grabbed = resized;
                }
                Frame frame = grabberConverter.convert(grabbed);
                image = paintConverter.getBufferedImage(frame);
                canvas.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000); // slow it down
            }
            // All done; clean up
            grabber.stop();
            grabber.release();
            grabber = null;
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method for the webcam test application
     * 
     * @param args  ignored
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new WebcamTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have configured my path:
[image: Windows system path environment]

I have my netbeans environment where i imported the nessary dependencies
[image: netbeans environment]

And my opencv/build/java/x64/bin
[image: opencv bin]

My system specification:
Windows 7 ultimate 64-bits
Intel core i7-620m
2.66ghz processor speed
4GB ram

And I am using Opencv 2.4.9 and JavaCV 1.1

I got this output when i run it
[image: blank screen]

What could be the possible problem? What am i not doing right? Or is it a possible bug in JavaCV 1.1?

Comment: Rule number one: **never ever** go with empty catch blocks. Most likely, you are doing something wrong, and there is a helpful exception that tries you to tell you that; but you choose to ignore that exception. Thus: before spending a lot of times on creating screen shares and writing up questions ... you might better spent some more time with your code to ensure you get all the available error information first. Not saying that this a bad question; but probably one that can't be answered. Because we dont need screen shots of file names, but exception stack traces!

Comment: @Jägermeister I was just showiing my observations. As you can see from my screenshots and question. I did not say that it throws error but shows a black screen

Comment: What I am telling you is that you miss the crucial point: a) your source code has an **empty** catch block. b) there is really no point in showing screen shot of file names. **You** should understand your system, so when you are running with tool in version x.y.z; then just tell us so. You don't need to "prove" that it is x.y.z. And finally: even when your file explorer shows that that you have a certain file on your system; this doesn't necessarily mean that your system is **really** configured to use exactly that file from that directory.